# test for java code for loop coming up with failed tests

Tags: java, loops, variable-assignment, bluej

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BAO8.png)    /** Check that the borders of each cell are consistent with
         * its neighbours. For instance, if a cell has no east wall,
         * then its neighbour to the east should have no *west* wall.
         * 
         * Specifically: for every cell in the grid, and for every direction,
         * the cell may have a wall in that direction if 
         * the wall is on the edge of the grid, and must have a wall
         * in that direction if its neighbour
         * in that direction has a corresponding wall.
         * 
         * @return Whether the cells in the grid have valid border values.
         */
        public boolean bordersAreValid() {
            boolean result = true; 
            for (int j=0; j< this.cells.length; j++) {
                for (int i=0;i

```
                   if (i==0 && !this.cells[j][i].hasWest()) {
                       result = false;
                   }

                   if (j== this.cells.length -1 && this.cells[j][i].hasSouth()) {
                       result = false;
                   }

                   if (i== this.cells.length -1 && this.cells[j][i].hasEast()) {
                       result = false;
                   }
               } else {
                   Cell northneighbour; Cell southneighbour; Cell eastNeighbour; Cell westNeighbour;
                   northneighbour = this.cells[j-1][i];
                   southneighbour = this.cells[j+1][i];
                   eastNeighbour  = this.cells[j][i+1];
                   westNeighbour  = this.cells[j][i-1];

                   if (this.cells[j][i].hasNorth() && !northneighbour.hasSouth() ){
                       result = false;
                   }

                   if (this.cells[j][i].hasEast() && !northneighbour.hasWest() ){
                       result = false;
                   }

                   if (this.cells[j][i].hasWest() && !northneighbour.hasEast() ){
                       result = false;
                   }

                   if (this.cells[j][i].hasSouth() && !northneighbour.hasNorth() ){
                       result = false;
                   }
               }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post the error trace.

Comment: please show your Exception.

Comment: In your last four `if` expressions, you use `northneighbour`. Perhaps that should vary depending on the neighbour you're looking at, ie. n, e, w, s.

Comment: i added a photo of the errors

Comment: Don't add photos - please include the compiler error or stacktrace directly.

Comment: sorry i think i may have asked the wrong thing there are no errors in my code but my tests come up as failed and i don't know what I'm doing wrong